# speeding up many accesses to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a dataframe to store information about which people take which drug. There are about 16000 rows in a multiindex describing characteristics of people, and 1000 columns of different drugs. 
[example table excerpt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J80Zv.png).

I use this DataFrame to aggregate information for millions of people: for each person, I query multiple databases and do some string parsing to get the information about the person's characteristics and which drugs they take. Thus I can't do any direct join/merge. Then, for that person, I do an access into the DataFrame to increment the values in that row corresponding to the patient, across a set of columns corresponding to the patient's drugs:

```
df.loc[(age, gender, etc), [drug1, drug2, etc] ] += 1.
```

This is very slow since I do it for each person sequentially.  Since I need to increment many columns simultaneously ".at" would not help.  Is the only solution to not use Pandas this way, or is there another way to speed it up? This DataFrame is only about 250 Mb so an on-disk database like SQLite3 seems like overkill?

Related:
[Pandas DataFrame performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084338/pandas-dataframe-performance)
[Pandas dataframe and speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685230/pandas-dataframe-and-speed)

Comment: `.loc` itself is not an expensive operation. In order for it to get expensive you need to repeat it many many times. If that is the case, it might be better to define the general problem to see if there is an alternative to that.

Comment: maybe an aggregate? `x = pd.DataFrame({'age':[12,12,13,13,14,14], 'gender':['m','m','f','f','f','m'],'druga':[1,1,0,1,1,0],'drugb':[0,1,1,1,1,0] })` then use `x.groupby(['gender','age']).aggregate(np.sum)`

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem:  I am repeating it once for each person in the database.  The general problem is to create this DataFrame of counts, but I am open to another way to create it.

Comment: I edited the question to try to represent the problem better.  The database is >100Gb (millions of people represented) so it needs to be iterated through.   Concatenating all the data would not work. Unless I am misunderstanding your suggestion .

Comment: you should probably give more details about how the data looks and you are currently getting it in - from the sounds of it, I would either use SQL in the database, or do something like `holdagg = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(10):
    holdagg = pd.concat([holdagg.reset_index(),x]).groupby(['gender','age']).aggregate(np.sum)`, where the i and x are replaced by the largest chunk of your database that fits in memory.

Comment: Interesting, I tried it out, and I am surprised that is definitely faster! Thanks!  I'll see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 2):

I used jeremycg's comment.I was surprised to find that aggregate was much faster with the dataframe defined as follows:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(10),range(10),range(10)['count','denom']], 
     names=['year','age','visits','type'])       
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(idx),len(drugs))), index = idx, columns = drugs)
df = df.sort_index()
```

This took about 3.6 seconds to run:

```
for i in range(1000):
    age = np.random.randint(0,10,1)[0]
    year = np.random.randint(0,10,1)[0]
    visits = np.random.randint(0,10,1)[0]
    drugs = [drugs[drug_i] for drug_i in np.random.permutation(len(drugs))[:50]]
    df.loc[(age, year, visits,'count'),drugs] += 1
    df.loc[(age, year, visits,'denom'),drugs] -= 1
```

And this took about 1.6 seconds to run:

```
aggmat = {d:np.zeros(2000) for d in ['age','year','visits'] + drugs}
aggmat['type'] = ['count','denom']*1000
for i in range(0,1000,2):
    aggmat['age'][i:(i+2)] = np.random.randint(0,10,1)[0]
    aggmat['year'][i:(i+2)] = np.random.randint(0,10,1)[0]
    aggmat['visits'][i:(i+2)] = np.random.randint(0,10,1)[0]
    for drug_i in np.random.permutation(len(drugs))[:50]:
       aggmat[drugs[drug_i]][i] = 1
       aggmat[drugs[drug_i]][i+1] = -1
z = pd.DataFrame(aggmat).groupby(['age','year','visits','type']).sum() 
df.loc[z.index,:] += z
```